# KendoUI Grid - Complex JSON with inconsistent keys

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I know this is probably been asked before, but having tried to find an answer - I am guessing either I am not comprehending some of the answers right, or I am looking at the problem all wrong.

I am using a complex SLC loopback query - and the api returns the JSON in the following format:

```
> [ {"id":"1","name":"John", "type":"commercial", 
> "address":{"street1":"1 dalhousie lane", "street2":"some street"}},

> {"id":"2","name":"Jane", "type":"commercial", 
> "address":{"street1":"15 dalhousie lane", "postcode":"1283833"}},

> {"id":"3","name":"Jack", "address":{"street1":"12 dalhousie lane",
> "postcode":"9383833", "geo":{"lat":"9393939","long":"99393939"}}}
```

]

As you can see, following are the problems -
1. Nested JSON - multiple levels
2. Inconsistent / Missing Key values, 
    e.g.: "id":"2" -> "type" -> missing
    e.g.: "id":"3" -> "address" -> "geo"

When I try to use the KendoUI grid to display the above json, i get errors such as - property undefined. I understand, options i can explore and what I am supposed to do -

1. Define the schema - how? Especially for missing keys.
2. Parse the data ?

Would be great if someone could kindly let me know, how to move forward with this. Below is the code for the grid -

```
                 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: apiurl,
                                dataType: "json",
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            field: "id",
                            title: "User Id"
                        },
                        {
                            field: "name",
                            title: "User Name",
                        },
                        {
                            field: "type",
                            title: "User Type",
                        },
                        {
                            field: "address.street1",
                            title: "Street 1",
                        },
                        {
                            field: "address.street2",
                            title: "Street 2",
                        },
                        {
                            field: "address.postcode",
                            title: "Street 2",
                        },
                        {
                            field: "address.geo.lat",
                            title: "Latitude",
                        },
                        {
                            field: "address.geo.long",
                            title: "Longitude",
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[column templates](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template)**:

```
columns: [
        {
            field: "id",
            title: "User Id"
        },
        {
            field: "name",
            title: "User Name",
        },
        {
            field: "type",
            title: "User Type",
            template: function(dataItem) {
                         return dataItem.type ? kendo.htmlEncode(dataItem.type) : "";
                      }
        },
        {
            field: "address",
            title: "Street 1",
            template: function(dataItem) {
                         return dataItem.address.street1 ? kendo.htmlEncode(dataItem.address.street1) : "";
                      }
        },
        {
            field: "address",
            title: "Street 2",
            template: function(dataItem) {
                         return dataItem.address.street2 ? kendo.htmlEncode(dataItem.address.street2) : "";
                      }
        },
        {
            field: "address",
            title: "Post Code",
            template: function(dataItem) {
                         return dataItem.address.postcode ? kendo.htmlEncode(dataItem.address.postcode) : "";
                      }
        },
        {
            field: "address",
            title: "Latitude",
            template: function(dataItem) {
                         return dataItem.address.geo && dataItem.address.geo.lat ? kendo.htmlEncode(dataItem.address.geo.lat) : "";
                      }
        },
        {
            field: "address",
            title: "Longitude",
            template: function(dataItem) {
                         return dataItem.address.geo && dataItem.address.geo.long ? kendo.htmlEncode(dataItem.address.geo.long) : "";
                      }
        }
    ]
```

Each template is a function that checks for the existence of the field and then returns the field value or an empty string.

> Working **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/oXaGe)**

Comment: Note: Doing is this way will most likely break the KendoUI Grid sorting/filtering features.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the use the schema.parse method to handle adding a default value for the missing field.  Here is a link to the documentation - http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse

```
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "yoururl",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    }
  },
  schema: {
    parse: function(response) {
      var items = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var item = response[i];
        if(!item.address.geo){
             if(!item.address.geo.lat){
                  item.address.geo.lat = 0.0;
             }
        }

        items.push(item);
      }
      return items;
    }
  }
});
dataSource.fetch(function(){
  var data = dataSource.data();
  var product = data[0];
  console.log(product.name);
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Wade

Comment: I would note that I think @ezanker has the best answer, but you may have a reason to use the answer I posted in some cases.